# Show that composition of maps belongs to $SO(3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations

Define $\operatorname{Im} H := \{r+si+tj+uk \in H : r = 0\},\, \phi(si+tj+uk):=(s,t,u)$, and
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im} H &\to \operatorname{Im} H \\
p &\mapsto qpq^{-1}
\end{align}

Let $q \in H$ so that $|q|=1$.

Show that $\phi \circ T_q \circ \phi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ belongs to $SO(3)$, the space of $3\times 3$-rotation matrices.

Then
$$
\phi \circ T_q \circ \phi^{-1}(s,t,u)=\phi(T_q(\phi^{-1}(s,t,u)))=\phi(T_q(si+tj+uk))=\phi(q(si+tj+uk)q^{-1}. 
$$

This is where I'm stuck as $\phi$ takes quaternions and the argument is a matrix.

I guess I need to show then that $q(si+tj+uk)q^{-1}$ is an orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N\colon H\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ be the quaternionic norm. That is, $N(a+bi+cj+dk)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$. Then, if $(s,t,u)\in\Bbb R^3$, $\|\phi(si+tj+uk)\|=N(si+tj+u)$. I other words, $\phi$ preserves the norm. ANd therefore so does $\phi^{-1}$.

Note that $T_q$ is also norm-preserving: if $p\in\operatorname{Im}H$, then$$N(T_q(p))=N(qpq^{-1})=N(q)N(p)N(q)^{-1}=N(p).$$

But then, if $(s,t,u)\in\Bbb R^3$,$$\begin{align}\left\|\phi\bigl(T_q\bigl(\phi^{-1}(s,t,u)\bigr)\bigr)\right\|&=N\bigl(T_q\bigl(\phi^{-1}(s,t,u)\bigr)\bigr)\\&=N\bigl(\phi^{-1}(s,t,u)\bigr)\\&=\|(s,t,u)\|.\end{align}$$

So, $\phi\circ T_q\circ\phi^{-1}\in O(3)$. But the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\operatorname{Im}H&\longrightarrow&O(3)\\q&\mapsto&\phi\circ T_q\circ\phi^{-1}\end{array}$$is continuous and its domain is connected. Therefore, its range is connected. Since the identity matrix belongs to the range, the range is a subset of $SO(3)$, which is the connected component of $O(3)$ to which the identity matrix belongs.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me why we can say that $\phi \circ T_q \circ \phi^{-1}$ is in $O(3)$ or why this shows that it is orthogonal?

Comment: Because it is norm-preserving; $O(3)$ is the set of all norm-preserving maps from $\Bbb R^3$ onto itself.

Comment: Could you maybe give me more detail on that? As I see, the output of $\phi$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but the definition I have found says that $O(n)$ is the group of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: But the question is about whether or not $\phi\circ T_q\circ\phi^{-1}\in SO(3)$, for each quaternion $q$ such that $|q|=1$. And I hope that you agree that $\phi\circ T_q\circ\phi^{-1}$ is *not* a matrix; it's a linear map from $\Bbb R^3$ into itself. So, in this context, asserting that $\phi\circ T_q\circ\phi^{-1}\in SO(3)$ means that the linear map $\phi\circ T_q\circ\phi^{-1}$ preserves norms and that its determinant is $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm still having trouble understanding this. Could you maybe give me a resource where it states that $O(3)$ is the set of all norm-preserving maps from R^3
 onto itself as I only find the definition of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at John Stillwell's *Naive Lie theory*. At section 3.2, he writes “If we drop the requirement that orientation be preserved, then we get a larger group of transformations of $\Bbb R^n$ called the orthogonal group $O(n)$.” As you can see, he regards $O(n)$ as a group of linear transformations, rather than a group of matrices.